# Multer does not find the folder that does exist to save images

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, multer

I am trying to upload images using Multer and although the destination folder does exist Multer tells me the error that it cannot find the folder, this is my code:

```
import { Router } from 'express';
import { check, validationResult } from 'express-validator';

const path = require('path');

const multer  = require('multer')

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, path.join(__dirname, '../uploads/'))
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, new Date().toISOString() + file.originalname)
    }
});

    const fileFilter =  (req, file, cb) => {
        if (file.mimetype === "image/png" || file.mimetype === "image/jpg" || file.mimetype === "image/jpeg") {
          cb(null, true);
        } else {
          cb(null, false);
          return cb(new Error('Only .png, .jpg and .jpeg format allowed!'));
        }
      };

  const upload = multer(
    { 
        storage: storage, 
        limits:{
            fileSize: 1024 * 1024
        },
        fileFilter: fileFilter
    })

let router = Router();

router.post('/', upload.single('img'),

    newProduct
);
```

But when doing the test from Postman it tells me the error:

**Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\project\uploads\2022-02-11T03:17:32.711Zcloud.png'**

The strange thing is that the folder path does exist:

[image: route]

And more strange is that if I use the basic code of multer without using **multer.diskStorage** if I can save in the folder in this way:

```
const express = require('express')
const multer  = require('multer')
const upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' })
```

I really don't know why when using simply if it shows the path that exists but multer can't find the directory even though it exists.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I changed this line:

```
cb(null, new Date().toISOString() + file.originalname)
```

By this line:

```
cb(null, new Date().toISOString().replace(/:/g, '-') + file.originalname)
```

Replacing the colon with a hyphen means that windows doesn't seem to understand colon paths properly.